# Bizspark now over 2 months pending approval

Tags: bizspark

I just wondered if anyone has experienced waiting much longer than '3 business days' to get a yes or no to a Bizspark application?

I applied in October 2009. My business qualifies (as far as I can see). I selected my UK network partner, [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/), and I'm still waiting.

I did get an email response after about 4 weeks from a Microsoft Champ apologising for the delay and asking me the 3 qualifying questions again. Strange I thought, but I answered the 3 questions exactly as I had done in my first application and waited... and waited...

Still nothing by the end of November so I fired off another email to the Microsoft Champ but got no response. So, in desperation I hit the 'Contact Us' link on the Bizspark site and fired off a very polite email explaining everything and asking for someone to make a decision. The response was short and precise 'Contact your Microsoft Champ'. (Sigh).

Well, I've now started the developent using Eclipse, PHP, and Apache.

I'd still like to know why I've been ignored. I mean, even telling me 'NO' I don't qualify would have been an acceptable answer.

Anyone else had problems applying?

Comment: I dont think it needs to be moved, but you might also try posting on startups.com as well.

Comment: Had almost instant response using Rackspace as my "Champ" in the UK.

Comment: had similar experience. chased M$ enough times, they always seemed very confused and basically no help. gave up in the end and stole what i needed, err i mean decided to use open source instead.

Comment: Jeremy, Rackspace were on my list but I went for a developer community because I wanted.NET develpopment support and my hosting requirements are 12 months away. I wish I'd gone with a hosting partner now though.

Thanks Richard. I was beginning to get a complex after reading only good experiences. I'm sure it's great when you get through the system. If I don't get accepted by 11th Jan I'll be too far down the road with PHP, Apache, et al. to change. Shame, because I was willing to put in the effort to learn .NET. At the end of the day it won't matter what technology is driving the server end.

Comment: Yes, I am having the same problems. Rather frustrating!

Answer (score -1):

Guys, go for the RackSpace. The customer service is amazing. They responded to my email on Saturday night and got enrolled in BizSpark on Monday!

As long your business meet the requirements you will be ok.

I tried with HSBC as my sponsor as I've got business internet banking with them, but they failed miserably. The provided enrolment code wasn't valid, didn't respond to my emails either.

RackSpace is the UK BizSpark Champ! Good luck!

[RackSpace BizSpark Application](http://www.rackspace.com/forms/bizsparkapplication.php)